# Adding an "or" to string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```
Class person{

  int name;

};
```

I have a scenario here in which i'm parsing a set of Person objects from an arraylist.

I need to concatenate all the name(member variable) for the objects in the arraylist  seperated by an "or".

I have tried some conventional ways of adding an "or" at the end of each concatenation and 
removing one "or" from the end of the string. 
I know this is no good programming.

Comment: Why not? If it works... The alternative is using an index in the loop and checking each time if it's the last one or not. If it's the last entry, don't add the "or".

Comment: Who has a number for their name?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Might be some identifier. Kind of sounds like he's constructing a query, possibly SQL.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, a friend of mine changed his name to "Four".  At certain times during Roman history, it was common for sons other than the first to be given names that reflected their birth order, e.g. [Secundus](http://www.behindthename.com/name/secundus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is indeed the way to go. I assume you have an arraylist since you tagged it, you can use:

```
public static String join(Collection data, String delimiter) {
    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    final Iterator iter = data.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        buffer.append(iter.next());
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            buffer.append(delimiter);
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

// in your code:
join(personList, " or ");
```

Comment: Clean solution, good use of `hasNext`. Might wanna use a StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer since concurrency isn't an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of languages have a handy function called "join". For Java there's an implementation you can use in the [apache commons-lang StringUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29). So passing in :

```
StringUtils.join(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}, ":");
```

would return

```
"a:b:c"
```

There are variations of this method that handle collections as well as arrays.

You could get the names from the Persons using commons-collection's CollectionUtils.collect method, then pass them into join.

It's probably a good idea to use Guava instead of apache commons. [Guava has equivalent functionality here.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
String separator = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Person person : listOfPersons) {
  sb.append(separator).append(person.getName());
  separator = " OR ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no counterpart to String.split, join. There is org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join though. Doing it yourself, use StringBuilder. In the constructor you could guesse the initial capacity. Either check in the loop on length() != 0, or after the loop a remove or setLength. And then possibly trimToSize. The factual problem is, that the problem solution itself is far from optimal. But that is life.

In SQL "name IN(..., ...)" would be feasible too instead of OR.